# Kernel doesn't start after tftp load

Tags: boot-issues, u-boot, yocto, tftp

I'm trying to set up a rpi model 3b with a yocto distro and u-boot.
I've built the `core-image-minimal` using bitbake and I have the `RPI_USE_U_BOOT`option set in my `local.conf`.
The created image runs when booted from the mmc but I'd like to boot from the network using tftp but there are some pitfalls and configuration steps I'm not sure about.

**The kernel image and fdt file**
In the artifacts of my build I neither have a zImage nor a uImage, all I have is an Image.bin (with a more sophisticated filename). Is my assumption correct that this is the kernel binary I've to load using tftp? In the `raspberrypi3-64.conf` of the `meta-raspberrypi` layer I found the following note

```
# When u-boot is enabled we need to use the "Image" format and the "booti"
# command to load the kernel
```

For the flattened device tree I took the `bcm2837-rpi-3-b-raspberrypi3-64.dtb` that is also placed in my artifacts. A `bcm2710` would also be available...

**The u-boot addresses**
I load the kernel image to `$loadaddr=0x200000` and the fdt to `$fdt_addr=0x2eff8d00`, I assume these are correct because that's what u-boot uses if I boot from mmc regularly.

**The Boot Process**
I try to boot the kernel using the following command

```
booti $loadaddr - $fdt_addr
```

but I don't get far...

```
U-Boot> booti $loadaddr - $fdt_addr
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 2eff8d00
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2eff8d00
   Using Device Tree in place at 000000002eff8d00, end 000000002f000d0c

Starting kernel ...
```

I'm running out of ideas where I could be wrong. Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
When I run `iminfo` uboot responds with `unkown image format!` but I think that's because `iminfo` only works for `uImage` types?